# How to list the certificates stored in a PKCS12 keystore with keytool?

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate, keystore, pkcs#12

I wanted to list the certificates stored in a PKCS12 keystore.

The keystore has the extension `.pfx`

Answer (score 198, accepted):

If the keystore is PKCS12 type (`.pfx`) you have to specify it with `-storetype PKCS12` (line breaks added for readability):

```sh
keytool -list -v -keystore <path to keystore.pfx> \
    -storepass <password> \
    -storetype PKCS12
```

Comment: If you prefer a graphical interface utility I found Keystore Explorer, a open source GUI replacement for the Java command-line utilities keytool, jarsigner and jadtool.    http://keystore-explorer.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks for the tip @David. Nice to see the project is still active also, unlike so many other such projects!

Comment: excellent tip on that freeware tool - I generally prefer command lines but this is very nice

Comment: Should this work with (`.p12`)? I get `java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
`

Comment: This does not work with a P12 certificate store (march 2019, newest KeyTool version)

Comment: It seems like JRE8u202 can't read PFX files with a password in SHA256 format. I had to re-export the PFX with 3DES-SHA1.

Comment: This works with a .p12 file for me.

Comment: I used `openssl` command per the other answers and it worked. With this one `keytool', I am getting the output `Your keystore contains 0 entries`.

Answer (score 58):

You can also use [`openssl`](https://www.openssl.org/) to accomplish the same thing:

```
$ openssl pkcs12 -nokeys -info \
    -in </path/to/file.pfx> \
    -passin pass:<pfx's password>

MAC Iteration 2048
MAC verified OK
PKCS7 Encrypted data: pbeWithSHA1And40BitRC2-CBC, Iteration 2048
Certificate bag
Bag Attributes
    localKeyID: XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX 48 54 A0 47 88 1D 90
    friendlyName: jedis-server
subject=/C=US/ST=NC/L=Raleigh/O=XXX Security/OU=XXX/CN=something1
issuer=/C=US/ST=NC/L=Raleigh/O=XXX Security/OU=XXXX/CN=something1
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
...
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
PKCS7 Data
Shrouded Keybag: pbeWithSHA1And3-KeyTripleDES-CBC, Iteration 2048
```

Comment: Just to say it works for .p12 files also. Very helpful, thanks!

Comment: @PhilipRego sure you can, just wrap them in single quotes.

Comment: I wanted to see the alias aka friendlyname. Had to use  
"openssl pkcs12 -nodes -in </path/to/file.pfx> -passin pass:<pfx's password>"

Comment: .p12 files and .pfx files are equivalent

Comment: If you get a decryption error, you might need to specify `-nodes` and `-legacy`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72598983/curl-openssl-error-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported

Answer (score 17):

You can list down the entries (certificates details) with the keytool and even you don't need to mention the store type. Also, the `.p12` and `.pfx` are both `PKCS#12` files. Assume that you've the keystore file `cert.pfx` or `cert.p12` then you can use the following command to list down the content.

```
keytool -list -v -keystore cert.pfx -storepass <password>
```

**or**

```
keytool -list -v -keystore cert.p12 -storepass <password>

 Keystore type: PKCS12
 Keystore provider: SunJSSE

 Your keystore contains 1 entry
 Alias name: 1
 Creation date: Jul 11, 2020
 Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
 Certificate chain length: 2
```

Comment: Pls consider of explaining your code and how it would help, so that others can be benefited from this.

Comment: I used `openssl` command per the other answers and it worked. With this one `keytool', I am getting the output `Your keystore contains 0 entries`.

Answer (score 12):

```
openssl pkcs12 -info -in keystore_file
```

Answer (score 2):

What is missing in the question and all the answers is that you might need the passphrase to read public data from the PKCS#12 (.pfx) keystore. If you need a passphrase or not depends on how the PKCS#12 file was created. You can check the ASN1 structure of the file (by running it through a ASN1 parser, openssl or certutil can do this too), if the PKCS#7 data (e.g. OID prefix 1.2.840.113549.1.7) is listed as 'encrypted' or with a cipher-spec or if the location of the data in the asn1 tree is below an encrypted node, you won't be able to read it without knowledge of the passphrase. It means your 'openssl pkcs12' command will fail with errors (output depends on the version).
For those wondering why you might be interested in the certificate of a PKCS#12 without knowledge of the passphrase. Imagine you have many keystores and many phassphrases and you are really bad at keeping them organized and you don't want to test all combinations, the certificate inside the file could help you find out which password it might be. Or you are developing software to migrate/renew a keystore and you need to decide in advance which procedure to initiate based on the contained certicate without user interaction. 
So the latter examples work without passphrase depending on the PKCS#12 structure.

Just wanted to add that, because I didn't find an answer myself and spend a lot of time to figure it out.