# cURL OpenSSL error error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported

Tags: windows, curl, openssl, pkcs#12

I try to use curl on Windows to post a timestamp request. Authentication is needed, so I use p12 file. I get error message, but password of p12 file is correct.

**Command:**

```
curl --insecure --cert-type P12 --cert my.p12:mypassword -X POST -d @mytest.req <myTSURL>
```

**Error message:**

> curl: (58) could not parse PKCS12 file, check password, OpenSSL error
> error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported

**curl -V**

```
curl 7.83.1 (x86_64-pc-win32) libcurl/7.83.1 OpenSSL/3.0.2 (Schannel) zlib/1.2.12 brotli/1.0.9 libidn2/2.3.2 libssh2/1.10.0 nghttp2/1.47.0 ngtcp2/0.5.0 nghttp3/0.4.1 libgsasl/1.10.0
Release-Date: 2022-05-11
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher gophers http https imap imaps ldap ldaps mqtt pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS brotli gsasl HSTS HTTP2 HTTP3 HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz MultiSSL NTLM SPNEGO SSL SSPI TLS-SRP UnixSocket
```

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Meta: this isn't really programming or development, and would probably be better on superuser or maybe security.SX, but this is issue is likely to become more common as OpenSSL 3.0 spreads and I wanted to get the answer out.

OpenSSL 3.0.x (and up) by default doesn't support old/insecure algorithms, but until recently most software that creates PKCS12 (including OpenSSL 1.x.x) used such an algorithm for the certbag(s), namely a PKCS12-defined PBE using 40-bit RC2, usually abbreviated RC2-40 – and some still does at least sometimes, like the Windows 10 cert-export dialog by default. To check this do

```
openssl pkcs12 -in my.p12 -info -nokeys -nocerts 
# in 3.x.x add -provider legacy -provider default or just -legacy
# to avoid prompt use -password or -passin, see man pages
```

and I expect the output will include

```
PKCS7 Encrypted data: pbeWithSHA1And40BitRC2-CBC, Iteration 2048
```

See if your curl has an option to specify the OpenSSL 3.0.x providers and if so specify (fixed) both 'legacy' and 'default'. Otherwise, convert your pkcs12 like

```
# in 3.x.x
openssl pkcs12 -in old -nodes -provider legacy -provider default -out temp && openssl pkcs12 -in temp -export -out new
# or simpler
openssl pkcs12 -in old -nodes -legacy -out temp && openssl pkcs12 -in temp -export -out new

# in 1.x.x
openssl pkcs12 -in old -nodes -out temp && openssl pkcs12 -in temp -export -descert -out new 

# and in either case securely delete temp; on systems with a memory tmpfs, 
# typically /tmp, putting the file there can help assure this

# IFF 'old' was created by software that put the keybag before the certbag,
# which you can infer from the order displayed by pkcs12 -info,
# you can skip the temp file and pipe directly from one openssl to the other
# compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/54469754/95735 found by @PiotrDobrogost
```

Conversion loses any 'friendlyname' set in the existing file. For curl, and probably most other programs, this doesn't matter, but if you want to use this same file with something where friendlyname *does* matter, add `-name $name` on the `-export` part.

Comment: Hey, so if RC2-40 is old & unsecure, which algorithm should be used?

Comment: @user3677636: certs don't really need to be encrypted, because the point of public-key crypto is that public keys, and certs, can be public. So RC2-40 isn't actually a vulnerabililty, but it is a wart: it looks silly to encrypt but do it badly. Nicer options are to not encrypt _at all_ which `openssl` can do with `-certpbe NONE` but other software maybe not, or to use the same PBE-SHA1-3DES traditionally used for keybag(s), which is what all my commands above do (3.0.x uses that by default, and 1.x.x with `-descert` does the same in spite of saying `des` and not `3des` or `tdes` etc)

Comment: This solution allow you to convert given [`test_cert.p12`  by czech Raiffeisenbank](   https://developers.rb.cz/premium/documentation/02rbczpremiumapi_sandbox) for current curl, php, python .....  (succesfully tested today)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 would using `-keypbe AES-256-CBC -certpbe AES-256-CBC` in 1.x.x make it generate what 3.x.x would generate by default? The manpage for 3.x.x states that `The default encryption algorithm is AES-256-CBC with PBKDF2 for key derivation`, but is providing the string `AES-256-CBC` enough to also make it use `PBKDF2`?

Comment: @DanielF: mostly and yes. Using `-{key,cert}pbe aes-256-cbc` does force PBES2 and PBKDF2 in all versions, but 1.0.x uses (Hmac)SHA1 in PBKDF2 while 1.1.x and 3.x.x use (Hmac)SHA256. Also the _PBMAC_ defaults to SHA1 in 1.0.x and 1.1.x but SHA256 in 3.x.x, so you also want `-macalg SHA256`.

Answer (score 30):

I was getting the same error using OpenVPN. I was able to fix it by adding or uncommenting the following lines in the /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf configuration file:

```
   openssl_conf = openssl_init
   
   [openssl_init]
   providers = provider_sect
   
   [provider_sect]
   default = default_sect
   legacy = legacy_sect
   
   [default_sect]
   activate = 1
   
   [legacy_sect]
   activate = 1
```

This is based on the information at [OpenSSL WIKI](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/OpenSSL_3.0#Providers)

Comment: Worked for me, windows subsystem for Linux, thankyou!

Comment: Yeah, fixed my issue connecting to VPN with pkcs12 file after Ubuntu upgrade to 22.10 / openvpn 2.6

Comment: Worked for me too on Ubuntu 23.04.
OpenVPN 2.6.1 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] [DCO]
library versions: OpenSSL 3.0.8 7 Feb 2023, LZO 2.10

Comment: This was simple and worker perfectly without any extra parameters or the need to convert the input p12.

Comment: This solved my issues. I was getting errors trying to use Kafka with a PKCS#12 file. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

On Unix-like (Linux, macOS, Git bash, etc.):

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

This fix my problem
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/14532#issuecomment-947012063

Comment: But that doesn’t answer the question asked, which is specifically tagged for Windows. If you want to answer based on LInux, check to see if an existing question asks that’s tagged accordingly, and answer there. If there isn’t one, feel free to create one and answer your own question as documentation for people in the future with this question. But don’t post an answer that’s not directly relevant to the question asked.