# Newman unsupported at request inside Get command

Tags: postman, newman

[image: run command]
[image: json file 1]
[image: json 2 with v2]
[image: certfile]

When I run newman in de command line i get the error as mentioned in the title.
After some debugging i found the cause.

In de json exported i have a path variable that has the value 'v2'
if i remove this value from the json and run newman again. i get no error but i do get a badrequest because the api string is not correct without the v2 value.

"path": [
"v2",
"ondernemingen",
"{agbcode}"
],

results in newman error not supported

"path": [
"ondernemingen",
"{agbcode}"
],

NO newman error but a failed api call because the url is incorrect without the v2

Anyone had this problem before ?

debugging the json
googling the error
chatgpt

Comment: So you tried to edit the exported json then fired a bug to newman? it should be a question in newman github, not in SO.

Comment: That's step 2  indeed. I think it is a bug but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Anyone one ? Please

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, pls rewrite your question, steps and add more screenshots.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I added the screenshot. Kind Regards

Comment: From my view, there is nothing wrong with newman. It returned 400 means there is an api map to this path (without `v2`) indeed and you can ask dev about this.

Comment: The api is with the V2 in it and works fine with postman. Just not Newman. Thnx for trying anyway..

Comment: @JurgenWoen: Is this issue resolved? because we are facing this issue. please let me know if there is any solution. thanks

Answer (score 0):

For me the error 'unsupported at request inside' showed up as well. I'm using p12 certificates for the request. Are you using these as well?

For me it turned out the certificate I was using was done with an encryption that was not supported by openssl 3. with openssl version 1 it was still working.

I converted the certificate using the line

```
openssl pkcs12 -in old -nodes -legacy >temp && <temp openssl pkcs12 -export -out new
```

[curl - OpenSSL error error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72598983/curl-openssl-error-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported)

I hope it helps for you as well!