# OpenSSL reports export from apple keychain as wrong tag

Tags: openssl

- Mac OSX: 13.4.1 (22F82)
- OpenSSL: OpenSSL 3.1.1 30 May 2023 (Library:
  OpenSSL 3.1.1 30 May 2023)

I'm generating a cert authority and a digital identity using the instructions from [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2326/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014136-CH1-SECCREATECA) on Mac OSX.

Section F at the bottom "Convert If Necessary" shows the following command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in "Deep Thought.p12" -nocerts -nodes -out server.key
```

When I run it:

```
% /usr/local/bin/openssl pkcs12 -in "server.p12" -nocerts -nodes -out server.key
Enter Import Password:
Error outputting keys and certificates
4076BD4CF87F0000:error:0308010C:digital envelope routines:inner_evp_generic_fetch:unsupported:crypto/evp/evp_fetch.c:341:Global default library context, Algorithm (RC2-40-CBC : 0), Properties ()
```

What do these errors suggest?

Comment: `server.p12` is a PKCS12 file and is not PEM. **`server.key` is NOT a PKCS12 file**; since you used `-nodes` it is PKCS8-clear PEM format, as indicated by the label lines `BEGIN/END PRIVATE KEY` (see rfc7468). This is not PKCS12 and cannot be used as input to `openssl pkcs12` (without `-export`). The only 'info' you can get is the attribute comments in the PEM file plus reading the ASN.1 with e.g. `openssl pkey -in server.key -text`. This is not programming or development.

Comment: The first command that is erroring is from an apple technical note and is not working with the latest openssl. You're focusing on my troubleshooting of the problem, not the actual issue. I'll remove my efforts, but I don't know how else to solve this issue or identify what is wrong - the error messages are not clear and do not provide insight into the core issue. Your comments do not address the issue, but I do appreciate the knowledge. As this is for a server, it's definitely a development dependency artifact.

Comment: You **already had the correct solution for that error** namely `-legacy` for OpenSSL 3 up; it was _only_ your now-deleted 'troubleshooting' that was wrong.

Comment: I found your comments from the exact same issue from a year ago. What dave_thompson_085_2022 said back then was that pbeWithSHA1And40BitRC2-CBC was not a great encryption and you had the same legacy solution I did. Isn't legacy for OSSL 3 the 40BitRC2 of 1.x? These legacy keys don't work with xcode using http3, assuming TLS 1.3. There has to be some other consideration here Dave_2023.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72598983/curl-openssl-error-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported

Comment: Yes RC2-40 is and was a (deliberately) poor encryption, and requires `-legacy` in OpenSSL 3. However, once you convert your cert-and-key to 'PEM' (i.e. not PKCS12) with `openssl pkcs12 -in p12file -legacy` that encryption is gone and is no longer an issue. If the resulting file(s) 'don't work with xcode' then there is some other problem, which you might want to ask about -- and IMO using xcode does count as development, though I can't guarantee it.

Comment: Thanks Dave - worked! I would say the -nodes option is a bit misleading, in reading and your description of PKCS8 PEM format, seems like it has context associated with the same term. In my semiconductor world, we protect config instructions with keys easily. Our development was delayed by 4 days because of this issue - as someone who understands the details of this workflow, do you see a better way of organizing this from an industry perspective?

Comment: Also, does this imply that a certificate on a public domain generated with the method above would be less secure because of the legacy status, so then the best course of action is to purchase one from a third party?

Comment: As I said in a response comment on #72598983, the fact RC2-40 is a poor encryption doesn't matter to security because publickeys are designed to be public, and (with rare exceptions) so are the certificates containing them. I don't know what you mean by 'industry perspective', but certainly those Apple instructions could be updated. Or you could create your own CA, keys, and certs with OpenSSL from the get-go and avoid the Apple out-of-dateness entirely; I've seen plenty of Qs on Stack for that, as well as the OpenSSL man pages. ...

Comment: ... A cert from an _established CA_ like Letsencrypt Digicert GoDaddy etc. -- not just _any_ third party -- will be more widely _trusted_ than one you create yourself with _either_ KeyChain or OpenSSL, or even other methods like Java keytool or Windows Active Directory; whether this matters depends on what you or anyone else wants to use it for. LE is free (no 'purchase') and some other CAs may be at least for some users.

Comment: Yes, agreed. It will not work for a test server IP that is internal. Those certificates are only for public IP addresses. The only way I'm aware of is to create my own CA. That's why I'm asking about methods Dave - a lot of time would be saved with some generation scripts. Apple is posting instructions that do not work with the latest openSSL, apparently they are using libreSSL? This is crazy to me.

Comment: Your pronouns are unclear. If you mean certs from established CAs, those must (in practice) be for publicly registered _DNS names_, but you can have such names resolve to internal addresses using DNS or other means like a hosts file. (If you use LE with http-01 challenge, you need _a_ publicly-addressed machine for issuance and renewal, but you can copy/distribute the results to internally-addressed machine(s).) Apple does or did distribute libreSSL with MacOS AIUI, but the page you linked was written in 2014 and works on OpenSSL versions until 2021. ...

Comment: ... If what you want is just 'do it for me without requiring much thinking', you could consider [easy-RSA](https://github.com/OpenVPN/easy-rsa) which is based on OpenSSL and (AFAICT) available in brew and MacPorts.