# OpenSSL Convert PFX to PEM

Tags: openssl

I have been using OpenSSL 3.1.4 on windows server 2022.

```
c:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin>openssl pkcs12 -in wildcard.pfx -out wildcart.cer -nodes
Enter Import Password:
Error outputting keys and certificates
C47B0000:error:0308010C:digital envelope routines:inner_evp_generic_fetch:unsupported:crypto\evp\evp_fetch.c:341:Global default library context, Algorithm (RC2-40-CBC : 0), Properties ()
```

c:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin>

My desired sample output :

```
Bag Attributes
    Microsoft Local Key set: <No Values>
    localKeyID: 01 00 00 00 
    friendlyName: 67540A1D46714C918394E1A7B2B77E7D
    Microsoft CSP Name: Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider
Key Attributes
    X509v3 Key Usage: 10 
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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blah
blah.....
```

Comment: This is not programming or development and has been asked before (though not as much as I thought last time because I mixed it with the similar case for unsupported hash in nodejs 17 up); see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72598983/curl-openssl-error-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported and use `-legacy`